# Namespace for imports with Python and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

Long time lurker, first question:

I'm learning to implement PyQt5 in Python and I've noticed a few different ways of importing PyQt5:

One example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication
```

Yields a class definition like:

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
```

Another Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

Yields a class definition like:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
```

This would certainly make a large difference to the code, as you would be using a lot of dot-notation with one, but not with the other.

I have seen example code with both styles, and this makes it difficult to use code from various examples as the namespace is different in each example.

So, in short, is there a *preferred* way to create the PyQt namespace in Python?

Comment: Namespacing all classes should be preferred in example/tutorial code, because it makes it clear which module the classes are coming from (which is especially helpful for newbies). For your own code, just use whatever approach works best for you. Inviting opinions on this is completely off-topic for SO.